# ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll Password

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel (2007) file (.xtlm) that has external connection with a database (MSQRY32).

I normally add a userform, the user fills it and then I go get the external data with this:
`With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array(...;PWD=____;...`

But now I wanna already have some cells with the external connection and I wanna use:
`ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

The problem I'm having is with the passwords, I don't know where I add them.
I have to add the `Password:="____"` or `PDW=____` somewhere.

I don't want this to show:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PGSb.png

This is really important.
This will be run automatically by a server and I need to refresh everything when I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution without VBA.

I went to the menu **Data**, button **Connections**, then each connection's **Properties**, tab **Definition**, and check the **Save Password**.

It seems to work fine and that looks like it also works for if I had 1 password for each connection!